# Can I run a PGLS model with explanatory variables in different units?

Tags: predictor, lm

I am looking at the effect of altitude on a trait and I want to include the effect of the interaction between latitude and altitude, using a PGLS. Can I include altitude (measured in metres) as one explanatory variable and latitude (measured in degrees) as another? Or would the fact that the two variables are measured using different units be a problem?

Comment: Hi @PowellHall. I am not familiar with PGLS, although I am familiar with OLS etc. If PGLS is anything like OLS, then it doesn't matter (in theory) that the units are different. In practice, occasionally there can be issues in model fitting if the order of magnitude is quite different.